# git remote repository and login server

Tags: git, ssh

I have a git repository on a server to which I only can connect via a login server. 
I usualy make a ssh connect to the gitserver with this command:

```
ssh loginserver -t ssh gitserver
```

Can I use this in git too, in order to get a working remote repo?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure SSH to do this whenever you want to connect to `gitserver`, so also when Git calls SSH. Put the following stanze in `.ssh/config`:

```
Host gitserver
    Hostname gitserver.full.domain.name
    ProxyCommand ssh -q loginserver nc %h %p
```

`ssh gitserver` will now connect to `loginserver` and execute `nc` (netcat) there to get to `gitserver`. Obviously, netcat has to be installed on `loginserver` for this to work.